# Select-Object -unique does not display all properties when used multiple times in a single .PS1 file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing a script that summarizes a set of `PSObject` objects using `select-object PropertyX -unique` to summarize distinct values for a few properties.  However subsequent calls in the same .ps1 file will only write the property selected in the first query:

```
$obj1 = new-object PSObject -Property @{a='a1';b='b1'}
$obj2 = new-object PSObject -Property @{a='a2';b='b2'}
$col = $obj1,$obj2

write-host "select distinct a"
$col | select-object -unique a
write-host "select distnct b"
$col | select-object -unique b
write-host "end"
```

Output:

```
select distinct a

a                                                                                                                           
-                                                                                                                           
a1                                                                                                                          
a2                                                                                                                          
select distnct b


end
```

the second command does output a blank line for each object in the pipeline, but it does not show any text.

If you flip the order of the commands you can get only property B to show up.  Basically it appears that write-output has memorized the columns to display.  Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

You can see this behavior by either saving the statements in a .ps1 file and executing it, or by running them all in powershell_ise.exe.  Running them one by one on the command line works as expected.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Is this code verbatim?

Comment: Hi Chris clarified that this only happens when executing a .ps1 or when running all commands at once in powershell_ise.exe

Comment: Huh, interesting. That seems like a design flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Adil Hindistan says, if you run commands one by one then all works fine. If you run commands altogether you confuse formatting because two kinds of objects are formatted at the same time. `Out-String` may help to work around (separate two kinds of objects on formatting):

```
write-host "select distinct a"
$col | select-object -unique a | out-string
write-host "select distnct b"
$col | select-object -unique b | out-string
write-host "end"
```